# Не срабатывает required у select в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, валидация

Имеется следующая ситуация, есть на странице две кнопки, которые лежат рядом друг с другом <kbd>Сформировать программу из краткосрочно плана</kbd> и <kbd>Сформировать отчет сравнение с краткосрочным планом</kbd> по нажатию на которые открывается модальное окно:

HTML-код модального окна и кнопок открытия модального окна:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-generate-program-from-plan" value="Сформировать программу из краткосрочно плана" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="get-report-compare-with-plan" value="Сформировать отчет сравнение с краткосрочным планом" />

<div id="modal-choise-plan" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <input type="hidden" id="btn-click-type" />
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Выбор краткосрочного плана</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
        <p>Выберите из предложенного списка краткосрочный план, на основании которого будут произведены действия.</p>
        <select id="choise-plan" required>
           <option selected value="">--Выберите план--</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="btn-choise-plan-ok"></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если нажать на одну из кнопок, то модальное окно выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JavaScript код, который обрабатывает нажатия на кнопки на странице, в том числе и в модальном окне:

```
function fillChoisePlanSelector() {
  console.log('fillChoisePlanSelector');

  $.get('@Url.Action("GetShortTermPlanList", "Programs")', {
      year: 2016 })
    .done(function(result) {
      var parsedResult = JSON.parse(result);
      $.each(parsedResult, function(index, elem) {
        $('#choise-plan')
          .append($('<option>', {
            value: elem.Id,
            text: elem.Name
          }));
      });

      AjaxAbsoluteLoaderOff();
      $('#modal-choise-plan').modal();
    })
    .error(function() {
      AjaxAbsoluteLoaderOff();
    });
}

$('#btn-generate-program-from-plan').click(function() {
  AjaxAbsoluteLoaderOn();
  $('#btn-click-type').val('generate-program-from-plan');
  $('#btn-choise-plan-ok').text('Сформировать программу');
  fillChoisePlanSelector();
});

$('#get-report-compare-with-plan').click(function() {
  AjaxAbsoluteLoaderOn();
  $('#btn-click-type').val('report-compare-with-plan');
  $('#btn-choise-plan-ok').text('Сформировать отчет');
  fillChoisePlanSelector();
});

$('#btn-choise-plan-ok').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($('#btn-click-type').val() === 'report-compare-with-plan') {
    //TODO: Сформировать отчет
    console.log('Сформировать отчет');
  } else {
    //TODO: Сформировать программу
    console.log('Сформировать программу');
  }
});
```

*Вроде бы все хорошо*, но имеется проблема. Если нажать на выпадающий список, то видно, что `required` работает и строки внутри него красные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Но вот в чем беда:** если я ничего не выбираю (остается надпись <kbd>--Выберите план--</kbd>) и нажимаю на кнопку <kbd>Сформировать программу/отчет</kbd> (надпись меняется, в зависимости от кнопки, на которую нажали перед открытием модалки, видно в JS) то `required` не срабатывает, модалка закрывается и JS продолжает свое выполнение.

Что я делаю не так, в чем причина такого поведения и как исправить, чтобы `required` сработал?

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то required работает на submit event. У вас же тут нет формы в html, которая бы это обрабатывала.

Comment: теперь ровно 10k )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок выяснил, что если у кнопки убрать `data-dismiss="modal"` и в `JavaScript` убрать обработку нажатия на кнопку `$('#btn-choise-plan-ok').click` то валидация начинает работать. При любой попытке навесить обработку нажатия на кнопку - валидация перестает работать. Поэтому было решено перенести форму внутрь модального окна (она была вокруг модалки):

```
<div id="modal-choise-plan" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="form-choise-plan">
       <input type="hidden" id="btn-click-type" />
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Выбор краткосрочного плана</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
         <p>Выберите из предложенного списка краткосрочный план./p>
         <select id="choise-plan" required>
           <option selected value="">--Выберите план--</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-choise-plan-ok"></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
       </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И навесить обработку отправки данных с формы:

```
$('#form-choise-plan').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modal-choise-plan').modal('hide');

    if ($('#btn-click-type').val() === 'report-compare-with-plan') {
        //TODO: Сформировать отчет
        console.log('Сформировать отчет');
    } else {
        //TODO: Сформировать программу
        console.log('Сформировать программу');
    }
});
```

Оставшийся код остался без изменений. Таким образом валидация обязательного поля работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]